# UIButton setTitle not working inside timer after tapping on button

Tags: ios, swift

The timer starts and countdowns while updating the title of the button when the view is loaded. I've called `startTimer` in `viewDidLoad`. This works fine as expected.

However, the problem I faced is when I call `startTimer` from the IBAction. I've verified the timer is working and the selector is being called. The button title doesn't change tho. What could be wrong in this case?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton?
    var timer: Timer?

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      startTimer()
  }

  func startTimer() {
      countdownSeconds = 60
      timer?.invalidate()
      timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  }

  @objc func updateTimer() {
      countdownSeconds -= 1
      let countdown = countdownFormatter.string(from: TimeInterval(countdownSeconds))!
      if countdownSeconds > 0 {
          UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
              button?.setTitle(countdown, for: .normal)
          }
      } else {
          timer?.invalidate()            
      }
  }

  @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
      startTimer()
  }
}
```

Comment: Why is the IBOutlet object optional?  Is it even wired?

Comment: Are you sure you connected the button to the `@IBOutlet`? You have it declared as **optional**: `@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton?` ... and then you use an optional unwrap in this line:  `button?.setTitle(countdown, for: .normal)` which means *"if `button` is nil, just ignore this"*, so your code may be executing fine, but there is no button to change the title. As a side note, this: `UIView.performWithoutAnimation {` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: @DonMag Yes. When the view loads, the button started counting down. This shows the code inside updateTimer does work and updates the button fine. However, when startTimer is called from the IBAction, I've verified that the the selector is being called but the button title is not being set.

UIView.performWithoutAnimation is needed as the button flashes when the value changes

Comment: Is this the actual code you are trying? I had to add `var countdownSeconds: Int = 0` -- but otherwise, it is working fine for me.